# Auto export from Data Studio to Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, function, google-sheets-api, looker-studio

I am looking for a way to automate the export of a certain table from Data Studio to Google Sheets.

It can be a script or a function. I know that this can be done manually, but I would like to avoid this.
I tried with this, but it doesn't work

```
function importCSVFromWeb() { 
    var csvUrl = "DATASTUDIOURL";
    var csvContent = UrlFetchApp.fetch(csvUrl).getContentText();
    var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csvContent);
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Why don't you connect your sheet directly to the Data Source? What's the point of using Data Studio?